# hover over one element (....trigger hover for different element)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover

```
<div id="bos_hero" class="clearfix">
    <a href="#" target="_blank"><span></span></a>
    <a href="#" target="_blank" class="rules" style="color:#fff !important;font-family: arial;"><b><u>Official</u></b></a>
    <div class="greybar">Have you seen my baseball?</div>.
    </span>
</div>
```

I have the above: the '`bos_hero`' basically wraps the whole area as a button. However class="`rules`" is also a hyper link nested within. `bos_hero` and `.rules` has a hover effect (basically just growing in size by `1-2px;` **I would like to trigger '`.rules`' hover event to go off whenever `bos_hero` does.**

Below was my current approach; but didn't work absolutely at all -- any ideas?

```
$('#bos_hero').hover(function() {
   $('a.rules:link').css('font-size','11.5px');
);
```

Comment: Fix syntax error, and check then....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using css only:

```
#bos_hero:hover > .rules {
font-size: 11.5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a couple quick things that might help you get to the bottom of it..

1. Close your .hover() function. Developer Tools in the browser will flag it for you, it needs a closing "}" bracket on line 3: ");" becomes "});"
2. When using .css() parameters with dashes, use quotes ("), not apostrophes (')

   ```
   $('#bos_hero').hover(function() {
      $('a.rules:link').css("font-size",'11.5px');
   });
   ```

Comment: This actually didn't work at all -- no matter how much I tweaked. Thanks for the suggestion though.